# Determine which dates in a table are between two given dates

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a table with national holidays dates. I want to check if, for two given dates (begin date & end date) there are any holidays between and, if there are insert them in another table.

```vb
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim tblferiados As DAO.Recordset
Set tblferiados = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("feriados")
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("natHolidays")`
If (tblholidays.Fields("date") >= [Forms]![Form]![Text0] & tblholidays.Fields("date") <= [Forms]![Form]![Text4]) Then
    rs.AddNew
    rs!Date = tblferiados.Fields("data")
    rs.Update
End If
rs.Close: Set rs = Nothing
```

Comment: Where is tblholidays coming from? Your code is a little confused.

Comment: I think you mean `tblferiados.Fields("date")` insteod of `tblholidays.Fields("date")`

Comment: Thank you for your replies, I have solved the issue, just had to pass the controls with CDate() :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 If (tblholidays.Fields("date") >= [Forms]![Form]![Text0] & tblholidays.Fields("date") <= [Forms]![Form]![Text4]) Then
```

with

```
 If (tblholidays.Fields("date") >= [Forms]![Form]![Text0]) AND ( tblholidays.Fields("date") <= [Forms]![Form]![Text4]) Then
```

The `&` character in VBA performs a concatenation of strings

Comment: Hi Dave, thank you for the fast reply, I have tried it both ways and it doesn't work. I tried debugging with a break point on the "If" and what I see is that no value goes inside the "if".
I am using as input dates: 1/08/2016 and 30/08/2016 and one of the national holidays is 15/08/2016, so it should pass the condition..

Comment: Where have you set tblholidays to anything? Is its assignment correct?

Comment: Hi Dave, thank you for your help, I have figured it out. Probably, despite being formated as "dd/mm/yyyy" the value from the text box must still be passed as a String. I have changed the code, used CDate() on the form controls and now it is working properly :)